# Getting buttons in jumbotron in the middle and changing appearance

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

How do I get the two large buttons in the middle of jumbotron to vertical and horizontal align?

I would also like to change the color of the button so that it changes color when you hover your cursor over it.

For the size of those two buttons, I used btn-xlarge but I would like to know of a more flexible way I can adjust its size to my liking, not just those buttons, but any button. How?

Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap For Beginners</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Hello World">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<style>

    .nav button {
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 15px;
        margin: 10px;
    }
    .input {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    textarea:focus, input:focus, input[type]:focus, .uneditable-input:focus {   
        -webkit-box-shadow: 11px 27px 176px -18px rgba(19,145,36,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 11px 27px 176px -18px rgba(19,145,36,1);
box-shadow: 11px 27px 176px -18px rgba(19,145,36,1);
    }
    .wrapper {
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .jumbotron {
        height: 450px;
        background: transparent;
    }
    .btn-xlarge {
    padding: 30px;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: normal;
    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
       -moz-border-radius: 40px;
            border-radius: 40px;
    margin: 20px;
    }
    .footer button {
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 15px;
        margin: 10px;
    }

</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <form class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="col-xs-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="exampleInputFeedback" placeholder="Have Feedback?">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit Feedback</button>
                    <button type="link" class="navpill pull-right"><a href="#"></a>About</button>
                    <button type="link" class="navpill pull-right"><a href="#"></a>Contact</button>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <button type="student" class="btn btn-xlarge">Student</button>
                <button type="student" class="btn btn-xlarge">Business</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <button type="#" class="btn btn-block">By Loi Huynh, OU '18</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is what you need...

HTML:

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="buttons_div">
        <button class="button_1" type="button">Button 1</button>
        <button class="button_2" type="button">Button 2</button>
     <div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
float: left;
margin-top: 0;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
background-color: red; }

.container .buttons_div {
position: relative;
top: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 170px;
height: 25px; }

.buttons_div .button_1 {
float: left;
margin-top: 0;
margin-left: 0;
width: 80px;
height: 25px; }

.buttons_div .button_2 {
float: left;
margin-top: 0;
margin-left: 10px;
width: 80px;
height: 25px; }
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmukL6mc/).

Regards, Milan.

Answer (score 0):

As far as horizontal alignment you can use `margin: 0 auto;` which will align to the center of the parent container.
To change the size of the buttons you will need to use the `height` and `width` properties in css on the button then you can make them whatever size you want. For the hovering just use the css `hover` selector and then apply whatever styles you want on hover.

You may want to read up on css:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin.asp

Answer (score 0):

For horizontal and vertical aligning use relative/absolute positioning, something like this:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <button type="button" name="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
background-color: #ff0000; }

div button {
position: relative;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate (-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate (-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate (-50%, -50%);
transform: translate (-50%, -50%);
padding: 4px 9px; }
```

Your button would always be in center both horizontaly and verticaly, no metter how much you resize your containing div.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4htkr1sv/).

Hope it helps.

Regards, Milan.

Comment: The fiddle demo is exactly the look I was after. I tried setting jumbotron at width 100% and button (the two large buttons in the middle) to the position: relative etc. but it pushed the two buttons ALL the way to the right, out of the screen! Maybe I'm doing something wrong, how would you apply that to my code?